# zf2 get route and module name etc. in plugin

Tags: php, plugins, zend-framework2

How can I get the route-, module-, controller- and actionname in a **plugin** in ZF2?

The plugin is being used by a viewHelper.

I tried different methods but none seem to work.
These are two of the methods i tried

Method 1:

```
public function __construct(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $this->routename = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
}
```

Method 2:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $e = new MvcEvent();
    $this->routename = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
}
```

Comment: Which methods you tried?

Comment: I tried to instantiate the mvcEvent in the construct, passing it via the viewHelper but every time it returns null or a fatal error.

Comment: Please show some code to understand others what you doing wrong.

Comment: get the request and give it the route match like $e->getRouteMatch($request)

Comment: When i do that i still get an error (Fatal error: Call to a member function getMatchedRouteName() on a non-object in ...)

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Something like PHPStorm will give you autocomplete, i.e. when you start typing $->... it will prompt you on the methods available. Or go old school & var_dump the object & see what is available or look at the source code

Answer (score 1):

You can see in source code how it works this helper.

[Current route helper](https://github.com/tasmaniski/zf2-current-route)

```
   $routematch = $routeMatch = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
   if($routeMatch) {
        $controller = $routeMatch->getParam('controller');
        $action     = $routeMatch->getParam('action');
        $module     = $routeMatch->getParam('__NAMESPACE__');
        $route      = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
    }
```